# UIWebView doesn't scroll to the bottom of the webpage loaded/created

Tags: uiwebview, scroll

I have a UIWebView inside a normal UIViewController. The content of the UIWebView is programming/dynamically created in my program, and it could be very long (multiple table rows). Somehow, after loading, the page won't scroll more then one and half screen of content when swipe on the screen. Because of that I can only see the beginning few rows of data, but not the many others after them. Why is that?

Comment: i changed the number of rows for the content in the UIWebView, the hight of the content seems reflected correctly. and i used the following code to set the frame of the webview. is there anything wrong? i also visually noticed that the scrollbar range doesn't seem to reflect to the content change, is it fixed? 

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    CGFloat height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue];
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 40.0, 320.0, height);
}

Comment: the scrollbar is the one build-in with UIWebView. it does look like the range of the scrollbar was not set properly, when i do the following after the code above, the scrollbar just didn't scroll to the bottom of the page at all. 

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0, %d);", height]];    

btw, this is all observed from inside iPhone Simulator. didn't try it on the device yet.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290697/uiwebview-wont-scroll-till-the-end-bottom

Answer (score 2):

If you can't scroll to the bottom end properly using `UIWebView`:

1) One  way (Programmatically) to solve the problem is using proper autosizing to `UIWebView`.

```
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ;
```

[image]

2) Other way (Interface Builder)  to solve the problem is using proper autosizing to `UIWebView`. Go to Interface Builder->Web View->Size Inspector and tick autosizing parts in all places (As seen on Image above)

Comment: where can I find 'interface builder'? and where did you take that screenshot?