# UIWebView won't scroll till the end / bottom

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scroll

I have the same problem as described here: [UIWebView doesn't scroll to the bottom of the webpage loaded/created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843299/uiwebview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-the-webpage-loaded-created) (unfortunately nobody answered there)

I have a UIWebView with inside UIView, and it doesn't scroll to the bottom, it's actually possible to scroll it but it is bouncing back again, so I can't see about bottom 100 px of my WebView, what can it be?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry guys, was my fault, I just had to reduce the height of the WebView

Comment: You've been helpful to others, though :)

Comment: Incredible! I've looking all over for a solution, I saw this and didn't take much notice of it...I reduced the size by trial and error and finally it worked. It's funny how iOS 8 is just around the corner and this issue still persists from 4 years ago.

Comment: I will say better to set self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; instead of reduce high.

Answer (score 7):

I got this problem today. I had set the constraints wrt iPhone 4 inch screen.
So when I executed the app on iPhone 3.5 inch screen, it didn't show the bottom part.

The solution was to go to the Interface Builder and click the button to go to 3.5 inch form factor. (the one which alternates between 3.5 and 4 inch form factor).

Then select 'Webview'.

Editor > Resolve Autolayout Issues > Add missing constraints

This solution is for Xcode 5.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't scroll to the bottom end properly using `UIWebView`:

1) One  way (Programmatically) to solve the problem is using proper autosizing to `UIWebView`.

```
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ;
```

[image]

2) Other way (Interface Builder)  to solve the problem is using proper autosizing to `UIWebView`. Go to Interface Builder->Web View->Size Inspector and tick autosizing parts in all places (As seen on Image above)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to disable Autolayout for the web view!